# What is the major difference between Mule ESB VM and JMS component

Tags: jms, mule

I want to know the major difference between VM and JMS component of Mule ESB. Can someone help me to know it.

Comment: Go through this link https://www.ricston.com/blog/vm-jms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Mule documentation, VM transport is for intra-JVM communication between Mule flows. So, that means when you use a VM in your flow, you can communicate between different flows in the application.
A flow containing VM **inbound** cannot be called **externally** from external application as thus the flow is equivalent to a private flow used within the application. By default uses **in-memory** queues.
Please go through the documentation :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/vm-transport-reference

On the other hand as per Mule documentation, JMS is an external host, allows communication between different components of a distributed application and JMS transport lets you easily send and receive messages to queues and topics for any message service which implements the JMS specification.
A flow, which has JMS inbound can be called from externally unlike VM. Documentation is here :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/jms-transport-reference

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Within the application, if you send the control from one flow to another flow we use VM.VM can be used as both inbound and outbound.

Outside the application, for example, A application want to send something to B application(external application) there we use JMS.